# How to add disclaimer in webapp

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using spring and spring security in our application, and authentication is done through ldap. after authentication role is check with database, and according to role he was able access specific role pages. I want to add some disclaimer message in web app. after user log-in in application then disclaimer message is display. if user accept disclaimer then he will able to access application , else login window is displayed. Is there some way to call Spring  handler , or maybe there is a better solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We handle this scenario with an extra custom spring security filter.

e.g it checks if the disclaimer has been already accepted and if not redirects to a disclaimer page.

Comment: could u please provide details or code snippet regarding it
?

Comment: @pablojin: I tried to add security filter before authentication but not able to find out,where should i put this. Could you please provide detail about this

Comment: what version of spring security are you using?

Comment: @pablojin: Thanks for reply. i am using spring security 3.0.3.RELEASE version.